# Animate a switch using an image sequence

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-animation, uiswitch

I would like to know how to solve a problem I'm having. I have an image sequence that basically animates a switch.

[image]

I'd like to implement this in iOS. How would you advise me to go for that? Maybe using UIButton? Or rather UISwitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a rather simple solution (tap switches, no swiping possible), I would advise you to use two UIViews stacked.

-1- At the bottom, use a `UIImageView` which allows you to run image animations.

-2- At the top, use a `UIControl` which will capture the touché-up-inside events.

Alternatively, you could use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` as a replacement for -2-. The latter option should only be considered if the resulting control will not be used for iOS < 3.2.

As soon as your tap-recognizer (`UIControl` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`) receives the tap-event, you simply play the animation provided through your `UIImageView`.

For more details on animations using [UIImageView see its class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically on things like `animationImages` (an array of images).

As UIImageView does not provide you with a reverse animation feature, you will have to assign the images in the reverse order before animating back to the start (that is after a user switched it **on** and now switches back to **off**).

For a more complex solution (tap switches, swiping is possible), you may add a `UISwipeGesture Recognizer` to your custom control and use the status of that `UIGestureRecognizer` to select the currently visible image of your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 allows you to make animated UIImages. You can put the animated UIImage right into the UIButton and animate it on button presses. [Animated UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed%3aduration%3a)